# How can I have multiple onClick events linked to one element in HTML? And can I have them change href's?

Tags: html, onclick, mouseevent, href, replace

I'm building a page for a company I'm interning for, and can't seem to figure this one out. The code you see below is just a simplified template, so that I don't give any information about the company away (and all the style attributes are in a separate document, so everything in the code is alright.

What I'm having a problem with is making multiple onClick events work. For that matter, is using the onClicks in the comment tags even feasible? I want the text that says Further Instruction to have it's href path changed depending on the animal picture that's clicked.

Also, I can't use any JavaScript, so please don't suggest the use of any. Happen to have any ideas?

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="mainPicture">
        <img alt="" id="awesome" name="Awesome2" src="awesome.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="gallery">
        <ul class="popOut">
            <li>
                <a href="DogText.html" target="AnimalInfo" onClick="document.Awesome2.src='dog.jpg'"> <!--onClick="document.furtherInstructions.href='DogText.html'">--> 
                    <img src="dog.jpg" alt="dog"><img src="dog.jpg" alt="dog" class="preview"> 
                </a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a href="CatText.html" target="AnimalInfo" onClick="document.Awesome2.src='cat.jpg'"> <!--onClick="document.furtherInstructions.href='CatText.html'">-->
                    <img src="cat.jpg" alt="cat"><img src="cat.jpg" alt="cat" class="preview"> 
                </a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a href="ParrotText.html" target="AnimalInfo" onClick="document.Awesome2.src='parrot.jpg'"> <!--onClick="document.furtherInstructions.href='ParrotText.html'">-->
                    <img src="parrot.jpg" alt="parrot"><img src="parrot.jpg" alt="parrot" class="preview"> 
                </a>
            </li>       
            <li>
                <a href="LizardText.html" target="AnimalInfo" onClick="document.Awesome2.src='lizard.jpg'"> <!--onClick="document.furtherInstructions.href='LizardText.html'">--> 
                    <img src="lizard.jpg" alt="lizard"><img src="lizard.jpg" alt="lizard" class="preview"> 
                </a>
            </li>       
            <li>
                <a href="HorseText.html" target="AnimalInfo" onClick="document.Awesome2.src='horse.jpg'"> <!--onClick="document.furtherInstructions.href='HorseText.html'">-->
                    <img src="horse.jpg" alt="horse"><img src="horse.jpg" alt="horse" class="preview"> 
                </a>
            </li>       
            <li>
                <a href="ChickenText.html" target="AnimalInfo" onClick="document.Awesome2.src='chicken.jpg'"> <!--onClick="document.furtherInstructions.href='ChickenText.html'">--> 
                    <img src="chicken.jpg" alt="chicken"><img src="chicken.jpg" alt="chicken" class="preview"> 
                </a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a href="DefaultText.html" target="AnimalInfo" class="center" onClick="document.Awesome2.src='awesome.png'"> <!--onClick="document.furtherInstructions.href='DefaultText.html'">-->
                    <p>Default Image</p>
            </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="rightcol">
            <iframe src="DefaultText.html" title="Information About Animals" name="AnimalInfo" class="fixThisHeight">
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="externalInstructions">
            <a href="DefaultText.html" name="furtherInstructions">
                <p>Further Instructions</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but onclick attributes *are* Javascript.  There's no way to get any dynamic behavior in a webpage without it.

Comment: Perhaps don't use `onclick`, move your click-handling to an external script and assign multiple functions there. Also: you can't use JavaScript in order to *use JavaScript*? What..?

Comment: "*I can't use any JavaScript, so please don't suggest the use of any*" - but you're already using JavaScript?!

Comment: Guys, sorry that I wasn't clear. We can only use inline JavaScript. Due to the content management system we're building our site with, we can't have <script></script> elements or import external script files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just separate your commands with a semi-colon:

```
onClick="document.Awesome2.src='chicken.jpg'; document.furtherInstructions.href='ChickenText.html';">
```

Comment: Just tried this:

<a href="DogText.html" target="AnimalInfo" onClick="document.Awesome2.src='dog.jpg'; document.furtherInstructions.href='DogText.html'">
     <img src="dog.jpg" alt="dog"><img src="dog.jpg" alt="dog" class="preview"> 
    </a>

It didn't work. It just always opens up DefaultText.html. Please advise.

Comment: What if I have some third party code that defines `onClick` on his own and I cannot modify it (but still want to do additional click processing on my own)?

Comment: change `document.furtherInstructions.href` to `document.getElementById('furtherInstructions').href` and change `<a ... name="furtherInstructions">` to `<a ... id="furtherInstructions">`. Also change all the `<a href=... target="AnimalInfo"` to `<a href="javascript:void(0);"` (without the target=)